# radio group button in ngFor - angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

**My Code**

```
<li  *ngIf="k.minimum == 1 && k.maximum == 1 ">
    {{k.item_ingredient_group_key}}
    <input id="{{m.details.ingredient_name}}_{{i}}" ngModel name="{{k.item_ingredient_group_key}}"  type="radio" class="hide"  [checked]="m.is_selected" [(ngModel)]="m.is_selected">
    <!-- <input id="{{m.details.ingredient_name}}_{{i}}" ngModel name="{{k.item_ingredient_group_key}}" value="true" type="radio" class="hide" [checked]="m.is_selected" [(ngModel)]="m.is_selected" (ngModelChange)="m.is_selected = !m.is_selected"> -->
    <label for="{{m.details.ingredient_name}}_{{i}}" class="radio">
        <span>{{m.details.ingredient_name}}</span>
        <span class="price">{{m.details.price}}</span>
    </label>
</li>
```

*

how to repeat a radio button by using ngFor ., i tried the above code but if i select one radio button means all radio button getting selected ., i use same name for different radio button groups

Comment: can you share sample data for array in this question ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e082daba9812a23eebc996e7570c08b6

Comment: @Chandru did you get ?